# My SQL - Refer data from another table rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have no idea whether it is possible or not.
I have two tables:

Columns in **hospitals** Table

- hospitalID
- Name
- AverageRating

Columns in **ratings** Table

- ID
- rating1
- rating2
- rating3
- rating4
- rating5
- rating6
- hospitalID

`rating1` to `rating6` is types of ratings. Now By `calculation` I am able to get `average rating` of `particular hospital` in `ratings` table from following SELECT Query

```
SELECT IFNULL((SUM(charges) + SUM(behaviour) + SUM(admission) + SUM(properInformation) 
                   + SUM(hygine) + SUM(treatment))/(count(hospitalID) * 6), 0
                  ) AverageRating,COUNT(ID) RatingCount 
   FROM ratings
   WHERE hospitalID = '111111'
```

Above query works for me perfectly but this `averageRating` I also want to calculate in my hospitals table because I want to ranks hospitals.

Is there any functions in mySQL through which I can calculate average rating to hospitals table by referring ratings table.

Rating Table
[image]

Query Output Table
[image]

Comment: @AJ yes. It is type of ratings as I mentioned Rating1, Rating2 etc. they are types of ratings

Comment: Then you can try the solution I provided.

Comment: @AJ yes your solution worked for me but is there any way I can create similar kind of function so whenever I select hospital table in that AverageRatings column average score of particular hospital should automatically gets calculate. Because as I mentioned I need to calculate rankings of hospitals base on their average ratings

Comment: @AJ My only motive is to display hospitals ranking based on average rating. If the way I am doing it is not possible or complex please suggest me any other way

Comment: There is no such function for this. You have to write your own query. Try the second query. It will calculate averageRating and rank of each hospital.

Comment: Why is there a column AverageRating in your table Hospital? Isnt't the avarage rating just the avarage of the ratings in the Ratings table for a hospital? Don't store data redundantly.

Comment: @AJ I have left feedback comment on your answer. Can you please see it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the given table structure, you can try this.

**EDIT**

```
SELECT avgratings.*, @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS hospitalRank
FROM (
    SELECT (SUM(r.`rating1`)+SUM(r.`rating2`)+SUM(r.`rating3`)+SUM(r.`rating4`)+SUM(r.`rating5`)+SUM(r.`rating6`))/(COUNT(r.`hospitalID`)*6) AS AverageRating, h.hospitalID
    FROM hospitals h INNER JOIN ratings r
    ON h.`hospitalID`=r.`hospitalID`
    WHERE 1 GROUP BY r.`hospitalID` 
) avgratings JOIN (SELECT @curRow := 0) rank
ORDER BY avgratings.AverageRating DESC
```

**2nd Query** to get rank of a particular hospital.

```
SELECT tablea.*
FROM (
    SELECT avgratings.*, @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS hospitalRank
    FROM (
        SELECT (SUM(r.`rating1`)+SUM(r.`rating2`)+SUM(r.`rating3`)+SUM(r.`rating4`)+SUM(r.`rating5`)+SUM(r.`rating6`))/(COUNT(r.`hospitalID`)*6) AS AverageRating, h.hospitalID
        FROM hospitals h INNER JOIN ratings r
        ON h.`hospitalID`=r.`hospitalID`
        WHERE 1 GROUP BY r.`hospitalID` 
    ) avgratings JOIN (SELECT @curRow := 0) rank

) tablea
WHERE tablea.hospitalID=1 ORDER BY tablea.AverageRating DESC
```

Replace `1` in `WHERE` block with `hospitalID`.

Comment: why It calculates only one hospital?

Comment: With second query I got only 1 result. I have given rating to 2 hospitals so ranking should be calculate for both. Similarly as many hospitals have given ratings it should be ranked with their average rating

Comment: also I have given rating to hospital1 like this (10,10,10,10,10,10) so its average is 10. When rated hospital2 the average rating of hospital1 changed which is wrong.

Comment: Yes it is necessary because hospitals has 6 types of ratings

Comment: Some minor problem in this. As it calculates ranking on each ID of ratings table so what happens here is suppose if hospital1 is voted 10 times by 10 different person then each time for same hospital it generates multiple ranks. See my screenshot above. You can see same hospitals has multiple ranks. See hospital ID 446795 has voted 3 times so it calculated it's rank thrice. Ideally number of times users voted should get sum up & it should multiply by 6 & from each user total number voted should count to get avg rating of hospital & from that rank should be given.

Comment: Can you also tell me with this If I want to see particular hospital Rank then how it can be done.

Comment: You are welcome . You can do this by adding `where avgratings.hospitalID=123456` before `order by`. and do not forget to upvote.

Comment: then rank2 things also show as rank1. From Avg Rating 10 has rank 1 & Avg Rating2 has rank2. When I try to see only second hospitalID then instead of rank2 it shows rank1

Comment: Nothing Returned with this

Comment: Ok.. One last question is how do I execute this query In vb.net code. Because we use here @CurRow, In output it throws Fatal error i.e. Parameter 'curRow' must be defined

Comment: Sorry. But One more little help. I also want to include city under that. Means while checking it should have somewhere where clause to apply city because I wanted to check hospital rank in particular city. So is it possible? See my website link here www.healthsaviour.com/hospitals

Comment: This error is coming "Column 'city' in where clause is ambiguous"

Comment: if city is in hospitals table then use `h.city` and if it is in ratings than use `r.city`. Also check this link http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/alias.php

Comment: Hi. there is a problem in 2nd query where we trying to track particular hospital rank as per their avg rating. If hospital1 has 9 avg & hospital 2 has 8 avg. in both the case the rank shows 1 only. can you please see it

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand your question...

You get the avarage of a single record with:

```
charges + behaviour + admission + properInformation + hygine + treatment / 6
```

You get the total avarage hence with:

```
avg(charges + behaviour + admission + properInformation + hygine + treatment / 6)
```

I order to get it per hospital, you'd group by hospital_id:

```
select
  hospitalid,
  avg(charges + behaviour + admission + properinformation + hygine + treatment / 6) as avr,
  count(*) as rating_count
from ratings
group by hospitalid
order by 2 desc;
```

You can select the hospital data (e.g. the hospital name) along by joining the hospital table. E.g.

```
select
  h.hospitalid,
  h.name,
  avg(r.charges + r.behaviour + r.admission +
      r.properinformation + r.hygine + r.treatment / 6) as average_rating,
  count(*) as rating_count
from hospitals h
left join ratings r on r.hospitalid = h.hospitalid
group by h.hospitalid
order by average_rating desc;
```